# Order List<T> by enum

Tags: c#

This is driving me nuts but it must be so simple.

I've got a class, the value of Strength can be HIGH/MEDIUM/LOW:-

```
public class SearchResults
{
    private List<string> _categories;
    public string caseID { get; private set; }
    ...
    public string Strength { get; set; }
}
```

I do an API call and get a `List<SearchResults>`

```
var resultres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchResults>>(mycase.GetResults());
```

What I'm trying to do is to order resultres in the order HIGH/MEDIUM/LOW but if I do the following it goes by alphabetic i.e. H/L/M

```
resultres.Sort((x, y) => x.matchStrength.CompareTo(y.matchStrength));
```

I've (probably incorrectly) tried to use an enum: -

```
enum ResultStrength
{
    HIGH,
    MEDIUM,
    LOW
}
```

but I can't find a way to use it to force the order, if I use the following then it gives me a "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' because it is not a delegate type"

```
resultres.Sort((x, y) => x.ResultStrength.CompareTo(y.ResultStrength));
```

I've tried implementing various `IComparer<SearchResults>` and `Comparison<SearchResults>` but I just can't get it to compile and/or work properly.

Comment: What's about orderBy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify `SearchResults` class, then just change `Strength` property from string type to type of `ResultStrength` enum. JSON.NET is smart enough to create enum value from string name.

```
public ResultStrength Strength { get; set; }
```

Sorting will be simple:

```
resultres.OrderBy(r => r.Strength)
```

NOTE: If you don't provide values to enum members, by default they will get following values:

```
enum ResultStrength
{
    HIGH = 0,
    MEDIUM = 1,
    LOW = 2
}
```

So HIGH will go before LOW. If you want to reverse order, you can use `OrderByDescending`

---

Otherwise you can sort by enum value parsed from `Strenth` string:

```
resultres.OrderBy(r => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(ResultStrength),r.Strength))
```

Comment: Cheers for that...you live and learn!  I found that I had to do the following as the original resultres wasn't being sorted `resultres = resultres.OrderBy(r => r.matchStrength).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to integer:

```
resultres.Sort((x, y) => ((int)x.ResultStrength).CompareTo((int)y.ResultStrength));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the enums names a value?

```
enum ResultStrength
{
    HIGH = 2,
    MEDIUM = 1,
    LOW = 0
}
```

Then you could just follow [@eocron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940218/order-listt-by-enum#41940279)

```
resultres.Sort((x, y) => ((int)x.ResultStrength).CompareTo((int)y.ResultStrength));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use enum, you can make use of element's index in a reference list to order an unordered list properly.

```
var ReferenceList = new List<string>() { "Low", "Medium", "High" };
var unorderedList = new List<string>() { "Low", "High", "Low", "Medium", "High" };

// Now we order unorderedList by using element's position in the ReferenceList.
unorderedList.Sort((a, b) => ReferenceList.IndexOf(a).CompareTo(ReferenceList.IndexOf(b)));
```